# Upgrading Apache SuperSet and separating customisations

Tags: apache-superset

I have found myself trying to upgrade Apache Superset from version **0.35 to 0.37** or soon 0.38 as is about to get released.

Our version of superset was heavily modified, from code added to the default superset files to creating new one. We are talking about hundreds of files changed with **1 to 1000+** added lines Given this fact the **upgrade fails** with a lot of conflicts, something that was expected.

I would like to find a way to make the **upgrade** to the newest version and keep our modifications as well as making the process **easier for future upgrades**.
So far (until 0.35) we manage to upgrade to the newest version and solve the conflicts but it became more and more difficult.

The modification were from the front-end jsx files to css to python files.

What I tried and failed:

- make a patch file using

> diff <0.35 files> <our modified 0.35>

and apply the patch to 0.37 but this did not work as the files are very different between versions and the line numbers changed drastically as well as the folder structure is different in the newer versions.

Is there any way to keep our modification separated and make the process easier for future upgrades?

Comment: What kinds of modifications have you made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more you fork and has the main branch evolves, the harder it gets to upgrade, that is simply to be expected when forking software. Given current high velocity and general pace of change in the Superset code base, and the pre-1.0 status of the software, you can pretty safely assume that any work you do in a fork is likely to be fully revisited every time there's a major upgrade.

The way you prevent that is:

- extending only the things that were designed to be extended (plugins, extensions, configuration hooks)
- contributing your changes back into the main branch

Many of us have learned that the hard way in our careers. The typical realization is that overtime, the progress in the main branch offer much more value than your customization, and upgrading and applying your customization becomes hard or simply impossible. The usual solution is to look into your customization and identify the really important ones, and try to contribute them back so that they can evolve with the software.